# Why wont this addEventListener work when I assign elements to a class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I have two text inputs, and two date inputs. I created a variable and selected them all with a class using QuerySelectorAll, and put an click listener on it. The function on the listener  changes the textContent of a div element to "", or blank.

However no matter what, I cant seem to get this to work with QuerySelectorAll. It works if i run this logic and select one of the inputs with an ID, but not if i try to create a class which selects all 4 input elements. What am i doing wrong?

```
    const getSum = () => {
  const inputs = ['dateInput1', 'dateInput2'];
  const outputs = ['result1', 'result2'];

  const arr = inputs.map(input => {
    return document.getElementById(input).value;
  });

  if(arr.every(element => !!element)){
    inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
    const inputValue = document.getElementById(input).value;
    if (inputValue.match(dateRegEx)) {
      var sum = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < inputValue.length; i++) {
        const num = parseInt(inputValue.charAt(i));
        if (!isNaN(num)) {
          sum += num;
        }
      }
      const total = (sum - 1) % 9 + 1;
      document.getElementById(outputs[index]).textContent = "Your number is: " + total;
    } 
  });
  } else {
 document.getElementById("errorMsg").textContent = "*error* please enter two dates and two names";
   }
}

const sumButton = document.querySelector(".sumNumbers");
sumButton.addEventListener("click", getSum);

const dateRegEx = /^(19|20)\d{2}-(0\d{1}|1[0-2])-([0-2]\d{1}|3[0-1])$/;

function clearErrorMsg(){
  document.getElementById("errorMsg").textContent = "";
} 

const cLickDeletesError = document.querySelectorAll(".clickClear");
Array.from(clickDeletesError).forEach(function(cde){
 cde.addEventListener("click", clearErrorMsg);
}

const dateRegEx = /^(19|20)\d{2}-(0\d{1}|1[0-2])-([0-2]\d{1}|3[0-1])$/;

function clearErrorMsg(){
  document.getElementById("errorMsg").textContent = "";
} 

const cLickDeletesError = document.querySelectorAll(".clickClear");
Array.from(clickDeletesError).forEach(function(cde){
 cde.addEventListener("click", clearErrorMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`querySelectorAll` returns a collection, So you cannot directly add event listener to it. So use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get an array from it. Then use `forEach` to iterate and add event listener

```js
function clearErrorMsg() {
  document.getElementById("errorMsg").textContent = "";
}
[...document.querySelectorAll(".clickClear")].forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", clearErrorMsg)
});
```

```html
<div class="cell-1" id="centerElement">
  <div id="cell-1-nest-l"></div>
  <div id="cell-2-nest-l"></div>
  <div id="cell-3-nest-l"></div>
  <div id="cell-4-nest-l"></div>
  <div id="cell-5-nest-l"></div>
  <div id="cell-6-nest-l">
    <input type="text" class="nameStyle1 clickClear" id="nameInput1" placeholder="Your Name"></div>

</div>

<div id='errorMsg'> Here is Error</div>
```

Another alternative is use of `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`. This is because there is only one relevant element with that class. So using `querySelectorAll` is an overhead in this case

```js
function clearErrorMsg() {
  document.getElementById("errorMsg").textContent = "";
}
document.querySelector(".clickClear").addEventListener("click", clearErrorMsg)
```

```html
<div class="cell-1" id="centerElement">
  <div id="cell-1-nest-l"></div>
  <div id="cell-2-nest-l"></div>
  <div id="cell-3-nest-l"></div>
  <div id="cell-4-nest-l"></div>
  <div id="cell-5-nest-l"></div>
  <div id="cell-6-nest-l">
    <input type="text" class="nameStyle1 clickClear" id="nameInput1" placeholder="Your Name"></div>

</div>

<div id='errorMsg'> Here is Error</div>
```

Comment: actually i didn't include the full html, theres actually 4 inputs with the class

Comment: I feel like it's worth noting that as long as you're not running some super outdated browsers (which, if you were, the `=>` would throw an error anyways), you don't need to convert the NodeList to an array. NodeLists support `.forEach` as well as `for..of` syntax. They also have a `length` attribute, meaning they can be used in regular `for..let i` loops.